# Android Kotlin to choose Mutiple pdf file using Intent

Tags: android, pdf, kotlin

am bale to choose only single pdf not able to select mutiple pdf

enter the code

```
val intent = Intent()
intent.type = "application/pdf"
intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
intent.flags = FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select PDF"),pdf)
```

Comment: Remove `Intent.createChooser()`, as that is not necessary with `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` and may be interfering with your results. Remove `intent.flags = FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION`, as that is for when you are giving another app permission to read from a `Uri`, and you are not doing that here.

Comment: No its still not working